# Click To Deploy Cassandra Google Compute engine issue: Deployment would exceed CPU quota for us-central1. Limit: 8 ,

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I've been trying to use `Click-to-deploy` feature of Google Compute Engine and i get the following error when i click to deploy cassandra installed instance

***Deployment would exceed CPU quota for us-central1. Limit: 8. Decrease usage, select a zone in another region, or request a quota increase***

I tried all the machine types and then created a new app and tried it again and everytime it failed . What might be the issue ? how to get the click to deploy cassandra up and running ?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you'll exceed your CPU quota with this click-to-deply operation. CPU quotas are per-region based in Google Compute Engine.

You can check your CPU quota in `us-central1` region with

`gcloud compute regions describe us-central1`

Additional quota details are available in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/resource-quotas).

Comment: I did try using the other regions in which I've not spun any instance   , still the issue persists .

Comment: Are you able to launch instances outside of click to deploy?  What is your current CPU quota in us-central1?